# fading effect in iframe using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fading, fadeout

I am creating a menu where clicked links load inside an iframe with fading effect however, the old content just disappear and new content just blink while loading. anyone know how to solve the problem?

JavaScript code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

               $('#nav a').click(function() {
                    var page = $(this).attr('href');
                    $('#content').fadeOut('slow',function() {
                    $('#content').load(page, function () {
                        $(this).fadeIn('slow');
                });
                });
          });
          });
        </script>
```

Where content is the id of the iframe.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan no it's white, does it affect the animation?

Comment: If you use Ajax, why do you use `iframe`? The problem will be easily solved if you use `div` block instead.

Comment: Agree with @VisioN  The main use of iframes is to load content from someone else's page (like embedding a youtube vid).  If you are not doing something like that then an iframe is generally not recommended.